# ¿Puedo crear o tener un usuario por defecto para iniciar sesión en .Net Core?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

Quiero tener un usuario por defecto en mi proyecto para iniciar sesión, ya que la página principal será el Login, pero no voy a mostrar una página de registro de usuarios, sino que esto se maneja ya estando dentro del sistema, como puedo tener ya un usuario registrado, guardado como un dato estático o quemado dentro de la aplicación web con Net core